# Non-conformable arrays in eventstudies package R

Tags: r

I am trying my best at a simple event study in R using the market model. I am using the eventstudies package and one of the steps is the calculation of the abnormal returns, being `ar <- es$z.e - esMean`.

The authors of the package have provided an example for the xts object (StockPriceReturns), Events (SplitDates) and for Market (Other Returns). This looks like the following:

```
> library(eventstudies)
> data(StockPriceReturns)
> data(SplitDates)
> head(SplitDates)

            unit       when
5           BHEL 2011-10-03
6  Bharti.Airtel 2009-07-24
8          Cipla 2004-05-11
9     Coal.India 2010-02-16
10      Dr.Reddy 2001-10-10
11     HDFC.Bank 2011-07-14

> head(StockPriceReturns)
  Bajaj.Auto
2010-07-01       0.5277396
2010-07-02       -1.7309383
2010-07-05       -0.2530097
2010-07-06       -0.3167551
2010-07-07       -1.2771502
2010-07-08       -0.2827092
```

With this data, I would like to do an event study – see below R code:

```
# 10-day window around the event
es <- phys2eventtime(z=StockPriceReturns, SplitDates, width = 10)

es.cmr <- constantMeanReturn(es$z.e[which(attributes(es$z.e)$index%in%-30:-11), ], residual = FALSE)

ar <- es$z.e - es.cmr
ar <- window(ar, start = -1, end = 10)
car <- remap.cumsum(ar, is.pc = FALSE, base = 0)
rowMeans(car, na.rm = TRUE)
```

So, if I run `ar <- es$z.e - es.cmr` it returns:

```
> ar <- es$z.e - es.cmr
Error in `-.default`(es$z.e, es.cmr) : non-conformable arrays
```

I have looked at the original function (available at their [GitHub](https://github.com/nipfpmf/eventstudies)) to figure out this error, but I ran out of ideas how to debug it. I hope someone can help me sort it out.

Regarding the marketModel: does anybody know how to do the same with the `marketModel` function of the eventstudies package. Because here I'm not able to write es.mm (see below) due to the error message: `ROW(firm.returns) == NROW(market.returns) is not TRUE`

```
es.mm <- marketModel(firm.returns = es$z.e[which(attributes(es$z.e)$index%in%-30:-11), ], market.returns = OtherReturns[, "NiftyIndex"], residual = FALSE)
```

Thank you very much for your help.